# Create different variable combination

Tags: r

I have the following 2 strings -

```
 mystring_ad    <- "10:20:30"
mystring_pwr    <- "010:020:030"
```

I want to create a data frame containing all possible combinatoins  taking values from both the variables---
The data should look like -

```
10 010
10 020
10 030
20 010
20 020
20 030
```

I want to do it using loops. Can anyone suggest how to write the code for this using r

I want to add another column "Variable" from the left of the data.The no. of rows in the column should be equal to the length of the combination string("res" as mentioned in the answer. Further, the same variable names need to be replicated in all the rows . How to accomplish that?

the data should look like -

```
Variable adstock power lag
Var1      10      010   0
Var1      10      020   0
```

so on

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need for loops.

```
s_ad <- strsplit(mystring_ad, ':')[[1]]
s_pwr <- strsplit(mystring_pwr, ':')[[1]]
res <- expand.grid(s_ad, s_pwr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will definitely prefer danas.zuokas solution. But, just because I already started play with this, and you will may be interested in doing it with loops, here it is:

```
mystring_ad    <- "10:20:30"
mystring_pwr    <- "010:020:030"

mystring_ad_splitted <- unlist(strsplit(mystring_ad,":"))
mystring_pwr_splitted <-unlist(strsplit(mystring_pwr,":"))


ads <- vector()
pwrs <- vector()
counter <-1

for (i in 1:length(mystring_ad_splitted)){


    ad<-mystring_ad_splitted[i];
    for (ii in 1:length(mystring_pwr_splitted)){
            pwr<-mystring_pwr_splitted[ii]
            ads[counter]<-c(ad)
            pwrs[counter]<-c(pwr)
            counter<-counter+1
    }

}

resultDF <-data.frame(ads,pwrs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is a great help indeed

Answer (score 0):

**Using loop:**

```
mystring_ad <- "10:20:30"
mystring_pwr <- "010:020:030"

mystring <- data.frame("mystring_ad"=NA, "mystring_pwr"=NA)
mystring <- mystring[0,]
for (i in strsplit(mystring_ad, split = ":")[[1]]) {
  for (j in strsplit(mystring_pwr, split = ":")[[1]]) {
    indx <- nrow(mystring) + 1
    mystring[indx, "mystring_ad"] <- i
    mystring[indx, "mystring_pwr"] <- j
  }
}
```

**Easier option without loop:**

```
mystring <- data.frame("mystring_ad" = rep(strsplit(mystring_ad, split = ":")[[1]], each = length(strsplit(mystring_pwr, split = ":")[[1]])), 
                           "mystring_pwr" = rep(strsplit(mystring_pwr, split = ":")[[1]], length(strsplit(mystring_ad, split = ":")[[1]])))
```